# Android - Collection.shuffle return variables

Tags: java, android

In my new app I need to shuffle Colors from a list and then allocate it to variables. What do the variables return? I thought the variables return the color, e.g. `colorone == Color.RED`, but when I print them they return the values -256, -65536, -16776961 and -16711936, is there a way to make them return the colors?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{                   
       public int colorone;
       public int colortwo;
       public int colorthree;
       public int colorfour;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){   
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                       
                 setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);    

                 shuffle();                              
       }

            private void shuffle() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW);
                 Collections.shuffle(numbers);


                 colorone = numbers.get(0);                      
                 colortwo = numbers.get(1);
                 colorthree = numbers.get(2);
                 colorfour = numbers.get(3);


             }
}
```

Comment: They're integer variables, so they contain integer values. Where are you printing them and what did you expect them to print?

Comment: Use Strings if you want to read them. Color.RED is an integer value

Comment: I printed them to test it and saw it in debug mode. I thought they return the Colors, so are the values the colors? Is there a way to return the colors?

Comment: How would I do it in the code?

Comment: @MalteS Those integers *are* the color values. They're stored as two bytes each for the alpha, red, green and blue values. So 0xAARRGGBB.